# how to draw ER diagram in Visio 2007?

Tags: visio, entity-relationship

I need to draw ER diagrams in visio 2007 which look like below but it seems there is no template available there, how should  I do so ? thanks

[image]

Comment: I vote to reopen but move to programmers exchange as it is more general/conceptual in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the "answer" you were looking for perhaps by but I now use [mySQLworkbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html) for my ERD's.  It's going against the actual database, so you can even import an existing database into mySQL and then fire this puppy up and look at the ERD - presto !  That's pretty handy.  You can also edit the actual data directly using this product.

Its good and also free. Comes directly from the mySQL folks.